# Error in reading a multi-line string into an array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I am using the following bash codes to want to read a multi-line string into an array. I want each array element corresponds to one line of the string.

```
mytext="line one
line two
line three"
IFS=$'\n' read -a lines <<<"${mytext}"
echo "len=${#lines[@]}"
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
   echo "[$line]"
done
```

I expect "len" should be equal to 3 and the "lines" array should be properly initialized. However, I got the following result :

```
len=1
[line one]
```

Have I used the wrong "IFS" ? What are the mistakes in the bash codes ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong with your solution is that `read` always reads a single line at a time, so telling it the `IFS` is a newline will make it read the entire line into the first element of the array. Each time you `read` you'll still overwrite the entire array. You can either build up the array iteratively:

```
lines=()
while read; do
  lines+=("$REPLY")
done <<< "$mytext"
```

or by swapping the newlines for something else:

```
IFS='+' read -a lines <<< "${mytext//$'\n'/+}"
$ IFS=@
$ echo "${lines[*]}"
line one@line two@line three
```

Using `mapfile` (a.k.a. `readarray`) would be a more coherent, elegant solution, but that's only supported in Bash 4:

```
mapfile -t lines <<< "$mytext"

$ printf '[%s]\n' "${lines[@]}"
[line one]
[line two]
[line three]
```

Without the `-t` flag, `mapfile` will keep the newline attached to the array element.

Comment: `readarray -t` will discard the trailing newline from each line.

Comment: @chepner good catch. Now that I've logged into a system with bash 4 and actually read the `help`, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This while loop should work:

```
arr=()
while read -r line; do
   arr+=("$line")
done <<< "$mytext"

set | grep arr
arr=([0]="line one" [1]="line two" [2]="line three")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is wrong in your case, but here is a workaround:

```
a=0
while read lines[$a]; do
    ((a++))
done <<< "${mytext}"
unset lines[$a]; #last iteration has already failed. Unset that index.
```